# Прохождение трафика через iptables

Tags: docker, iptables

На сервере есть nginx, который при обращении к доменному имени например site.io по https перекидывает на контейнер с портом 3000. Необходимо написать пару правил в iptables. Но не могу понять. Приходит пакет на сервер. Т.к. https то обращение идет на порт 443, после этого nginx смотрит по доменному имени site.io и перенаправляет на порт 3000. Вопрос в следующем: Необходимо писать правило в iptables для порта 443 или 3000?

Comment: Если вы явно сами ничего не закрывали то ничего писать не надо. главное что бы в dns доменное имя site.io выдавало ip нужного контейнера. Если же вы все таки хотите писать некое правило, то сначала скажите что именно оно должно делать

Comment: @Mike нужно разрешить доступ только с определенных ip. Думал сделать через конфиг nginx, но сказали использовать iptables

Comment: тогда явно на 443 порт, ведь nginx лезет в контейнер уже со своего ip и клиентские ip вы там не увидите